# Why does database receive no data on a successful Django POST?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am getting a successful 302 redirect POST when submitting my form, but data is not populating in the database. I am trying to create a simple comments post. Take the comment, submit it, redirect to the one page back ('lists'), display new comments - fairly straightforward - but I cannot figure out why I am not getting any data in the database

I am using a postgres backend

models.py

```
class TicketComment(models.Model):
    ticket = models.ForeignKey(TicketList, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    technician = models.ForeignKey(TechnicianUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s -%s' % (self.ticket.name, self.ticket)
```

forms.py

```
class TicketCommentAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TicketComment
        fields = '__all__'
```

urls.py

```
    # Support Tickets
    path("support-tickets/list", view=apps_tickets_list_view, name="tickets.list"),
    path("support-tickets/edit/<str:pk>", view=apps_tickets_edit_view, name="tickets.edit"),
    path("support-tickets/delete/<str:pk>", view=apps_tickets_delete_list_view, name="tickets.delete_list"),
    path("support-tickets/details/<str:pk>", view=apps_tickets_details_view, name="tickets.details"),
    path("support-tickets/details/<str:pk>/comment", view=apps_tickets_comments_view, name="tickets.comments"),
```

views.py

```
def apps_tickets_comments_view(request,pk):
    tickets = TicketList.objects.get(pk=pk)
    comments = TicketComment.objects.all()
    context = {"tickets":tickets,"comments":comments}
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TicketCommentAddForm(request.POST or None,request.FILES or None,instance=tickets)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            print(form.cleaned_data['technician'])
            messages.success(request,"Comment inserted Successfully!")
            return redirect("apps:tickets.list")
            
        else:
            print(form.errors)
            messages.error(request,"Something went wrong!")
            return redirect("apps:tickets.list")
            
    return render(request,'apps/support-tickets/apps-tickets-details.html',context)
```

ticket-details.html

```
<form action="{% url 'apps:tickets.comments' tickets.identifier %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="mt-3">
                                            {% csrf_token %}
                                            {{ form.as_p }}
                                            <div class="row g-3">
                                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                    <label for="bodyTextarea1" class="form-label">Leave a Comment</label>
                                                    <textarea class="form-control bg-light border-light" id="bodyTextarea1" rows="3" placeholder="Enter comment" name="body"></textarea>
                                                    <input name="technician" type="hidden" name="technician" value="{{user.pk}}">
                                                    <input name="ticket" type="hidden" value="{{tickets.pk}}">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-lg-12 text-end">
                                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="add-btn">Post Comment</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
```

[image: Successful 302 with printing data from the form:]

[image: No Data In Database...]

I have made sure that `method=POST`, I have a `name` attribute in html, and can even print form data back in the console, but cannot get it in database. What am I overlooking?

---

**EDIT**

I took the route to try postman and still same thing... I set up CSRF, have a 200 on the GET and POST request. I can print back form data (tech name).... I am losing my marbles

[image: Postman submission with output and DB]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form was the line... I was referencing the instance `tickets` but this is the comments model.

```
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TicketCommentAddForm(request.POST or None,request.FILES or None,instance=tickets)
        if form.is_valid():
```

Should be

```
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TicketCommentAddForm(request.POST or None,request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():
```

Answer (score 1):

You're passing `tickets.identifier` to your url, but I can't see that this is a value anywhere, which means you have an invalid url.

```
<form action="{% url 'apps:tickets.comments' tickets.identifier %}"
```

Also, for this kind of issue, I suggest testing the view seperately from the form (write a test case, or use postman or something), so it's easier to know which part is going wrong.

2nd option:

Your url name is a little odd. Try setting `app_name` in the `urls.py` instead of forcing your names to be `tickets.something` as you are.

Then your url names can be just `list`, `edit`, `comments` etc. and your url shortcut would be `tickets:comments`.

See here for more info on `app_name`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces-and-included-urlconfs

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I will poke around in Postman, that is a good suggestion. I am new to building web apps, not python as much. With your comment, I am trying to refer to a specific ticket id to place the comment on. `tickets.identifier` is the PK on ticketsList model. When I change `tickets.identifier` to `tickets` I get the following error: `ValidationError at /apps/support-tickets/details/Test Ticket Edit/comment ['“Test Ticket Edit” is not a valid UUID` - Where 'Test Ticket' = `tickets.name`. So I can put in `tickets.pk`, same issue. Successful redirect, no data posted

Comment: Ah, OK, so you've specifically set the `id` on `ticket` to be `identifier`. Have another thought I'll add to the answer ...